# Gson custom type adapter to serialize null on one object type only?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'd like to serialize null for only one type in my JSON body that is going on a PUT.  I don't want to serialize nulls for any other types in the object.  I have something like this:

```
public class Patient {
    public Address address;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
}
```

and I only want to serialize address if address is null.  So for example

```
Patient patient = new Patient();
patient.address = null;
patient.last_name = "Doe";
```

will look something like this:

```
"address":null,
"last_name":"Doe"
```

Where address is assigned null, patient is left off of the object because by default Gson does not serialize nulls which is what I want, and last name retains the assigned string value.

Is there a Gson custom type adapter that I could use?

```
public class GsonCustomAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Address>
```

I'm not familiar at all with this concept and have been trying to understand it for awhile.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If, by default, you don't want to serialize nulls, you can tell the `JsonWriter` to serialize it only if you are actually reading an `Address` instance.

Let's assume the following class:

```
class Address {
    public String country = "UK";
    public String city = "London";
}
```

Now we create a specific type adapter for the `Address` class. This is here where you explicitly say that even if the `JsonWriter` is not supposed to write `null` values in the response, you allow it to do so just for the `Address` field (see the comments in the code).

```
class AddressAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Address> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Address address) throws IOException {
        if (address == null) {
            //if the writer was not allowed to write null values
            //do it only for this field
            if (!out.getSerializeNulls()) {
                out.setSerializeNulls(true);
                out.nullValue();
                out.setSerializeNulls(false);
            } else {
                out.nullValue();
            }
        } else {
            out.beginObject();
            out.name("country");
            out.value(address.country);
            out.name("city");
            out.value(address.city);
            out.endObject();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Address read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if(in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        in.beginObject();
        Address address = new Address();
        in.nextName();
        address.country = in.nextString();
        in.nextName();
        address.city = in.nextString();
        in.endObject();
        return address;
    }
}
```

Now you have to register this adapter so that the parser knows he has to use it when serializing/deserializing an `Address` field. To do that, use the annotation `@JsonAdapter`.

```
class Patient {
    @JsonAdapter(AddressAdapter.class)
    public Address address;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
}
```

And it's done!

For instance let's take the patient in your example:

```
Patient patient = new Patient();
patient.last_name = "Doe";
```

With the parser set to serialize null values, you get:

```
{"address":null,"first_name":null,"last_name":"Doe"}
```

When you don't allow it (set by default):

```
{"address":null,"last_name":"Doe"}
```

by setting an address for the patient:

```
patient.address = new Address();
...
{"address":{"country":"UK","city":"London"},"last_name":"Doe"}
```

---

As a note if you want to stick with naming conventions on the Java side, you can use the annotation `@SerializedName`, for instance:

```
@SerializedName("first_name") public String firstName;
@SerializedName("last_name")  public String lastName;
```

Hope it helps ! :-)

Comment: Wow. This was awesome

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to avoid re-implementing serialization of Address in the example? I want to set JsonToken.NULL when address is null, otherwise I'd like proceed as normal by using built-in gson serializer.

Comment: @Alexis C. can you provide a solution using moshi

Comment: Thanks! very good answer! The only thing to point out is that `out.nullValue()` throws and in that case `out.setSerializeNulls(false)` is never executed so it would be fine to add a finally clause there.